# Murata NCS6D1215C DC/DC converter for +15V and -15V

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I would like to know if I can use a [Murata NCS6D1215C DC/DC converter](http://www.murata-ps.com/datasheet?http://www.murata-ps.com/data/power/ncl/kdc_ncs6.pdf) with a 12V battery to provide the necessary +15V and -15V for a power supply and amplifier that together require 200mA.

The last page, page 9, show the pin connections 14 and 16 as +Vout and -Vout; 
For this unit the data sheet says the outputs are +15V and -15V.  So, does that mean that there is a potential difference of 30V between these two, pins 14 and 16?  If so, what do I use as the "ground" or zero voltage reference to get the +15V and -15V outputs from these pins?  Is it the negative terminal of the battery?

Does this IC require a current limiting resister to the inputs?  If so, should I place it at the positive or negative battery terminal, and how big a resistor should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Pin 16 is 0V, pin 11 is -Vout and pin 14 is +Vout. You need to read the table more carefully - look at the columns - one says "single" and the other says "double" - you read the "single output" column. Input and output are isolated so unless you have input tied to output 0V, trying to use the input for anything sensible won't work.

You don't need any current limiting - see absolute maximum ratings - it says short circuit protection is continuous.